# Add a printer in WIndows 7 produces a hidden printer

Tags: windows-7, printer

On Windows 7 Home Premium x64, I've added a printer that uses an existing driver, and named it 'Canon 2-sided'. After doing so, the Devices and Printers control panel does 'not' show the new printer. This makes it difficult to configure the new printer.

When I attempt to print a page, the printer drop-down menu 'does' show the new printer.

Is there some way to insure that the control panel lists the new printer?

Comment: Ok, I found that Windows 7 does NOT list all printers in the control panel whenever the driver for each printer is the same. Since I had a 'Canon xyz' pre-installed and then added a 'Canon xyz 2-sided' with the same driver, they were both combined and listed as a single printer.

To see and configure each individual printer, right-click on the single printer icon to get an option list where individual printers are listed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that the DRIVER is the same, but that the PORT is the same.   See: [Some printers are merged into control panel on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/611787/some-printers-are-merged-into-control-panel-on-windows-7)

Comment: Please post the content linked to avoid link rot

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.